# fluid content pushes down fixed right sidebar

Tags: html, css

Look at this url:
http://kraken.ikas.sk/

and compare to:
http://kraken.ikas.sk/autorizovany-servis

Why is my fixed right sidebar dropping under content? Css seems to be exactly the same.
I need fixed sidebars (180px) and fluid content.
If there is no sidebar on the right, the content must stretch to the right to full width.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
#main_content {
    float: left;
    max-width: 550px; // change this line
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: To get it to look like the first page given, the max width should be 543px - though, I'm not sure why it's exactly that width.

Comment: if you look to page http://kraken.ikas.sk/o-nas you will see that main_content must stretch to whole page to the right. So max-width: 550px, or width 550px do not help me.

Comment: Use javascript then. If `#right_content` div is not on page, then set `#main_content` to `width: 718px` else use `width: 550px` or whatever size yuo want.

Comment: Sorry, i dont want to use JS. I believe it must be some CSS only solution to this problem.